# jQuery Retina image replacement loop

Tags: jquery, retina-display

I'm working on a script which loops through all of the images on the page and replaces them with the "Retina ready" version if that file exists. The problem is that as the loop goes through each image, it changes the variables:

```
retinaText = "@2x";

$("img").each(function(){
    filename = $(this).attr("src");
    ext = "."+filename.substr((Math.max(0, filename.lastIndexOf(".")) || Infinity) + 1);
    filesource = filename.split(ext)[0];
    retinaImage = filesource + retinaText + ext;

    //check if images exists

    $.ajax({
        url:retinaImage,
        type:'POST',
        error: function(){  },
        success: function(){  
            //file exists
            //replace image with retina ready image 
            //$(this).attr("src",retinaImage);
        }
    });
});
```

I set up a test environment where the first image had a replacement and the others didn't, however since the loop continues to run through the images, the variables change.

If the images are set up like this:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" />
<img src="image2.jpg" />
<img src="image3.jpg" />
<img src="image4.jpg" />
```

And this image exists in the same directory:

```
<img src="image1@2x.jpg" />
```

The script ends up trying to replace image4 with "image4@2x" because the retinaImage variable and $(this) have since changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're declaring your variables puts them in the global scope. For example, `retinaImage` becomes a global variable, and it's modified in each iteration of `.each()`.

Use the `var` keyword to create local variables. For example:

```
$("img").each(function(){
    var filename = $(this).attr("src");
    var ext = "."+filename.substr((Math.max(0, filename.lastIndexOf(".")) || Infinity) + 1);
    var filesource = filename.split(ext)[0];
    var retinaImage = filesource + retinaText + ext;
    //check if images exists

    // ADDED: keep reference to current image
    var currentImage = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url:retinaImage,
        type:'POST',
        error: function(){  },
        success: function(){  
            //file exists
            //replace image with retina ready image 

            // currentImage refers to the correct image, and retinaImage refers to that image's retina URL
            currentImage.attr("src",retinaImage);
        }
    });
});
```

Local variables keep their scope within the current function, as well as [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).